# Where exactly the table-data stored using MySQL-cluster gets stored?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, database-cluster

I am a new-bee to MySQL cluster and wanted to know where exactly the data is stored in MySQL-cluster and where can i see it without directly. As we can see the separate files for each tables in MySQL 5.x databases. I have to verify for the same in Cluster formation. Please reply.

Comment: There should be some `DataDir` directives in your my.ini/my.cnf whichn specify where the cluster files are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, MySQL-Cluster is just NDB (Network DataBase).  Now, the NDB engine has a 2 main storage mechanisms.

1. In memory.  This has been available since NDB was introduced.  Basically, it's just a series of memory tables that store the data.  If all of your node sets go down, you lose all of your data.  So you'll need to either replicate to a hard storage, or backup often and replay binary logs in the case of a server reboot.
2. Since MySQL 5.1.6, NDB supports disk *backed* storage.  That means that the working set is still kept in memory, but all writes are flushed to a disk buffer.  So a restart just re-reads the disk.  See [MySQl Cluster Disk Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data.html).

   Another useful read is [this whitepaper (PDF)](http://www.vldb2005.org/program/paper/wed/p1108-ronstrom.pdf) about recovery principles.

Comment: is disk backed storage enabled by default? or must it be configured?